# how to find out where pdftex is used

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I am new to LaTeX so please excuse, if the question sounds stupid.

I am trying to use the following template, but when I try to compile it I run into a problem: I need to use `xelatex` for some packages as I require special characters, but when I compile it with `xelatex` I get the following error:

> ```
> !Package pdftex.def Error: Option 'pdftex' requires pdfTeX
> ```

However, I don't understand where my template is using the pdftex option. Which package is it? Or am I missing something?

```
% This one will format for two-sided binding (ie left and right pages have mirror margins; blank pages inserted where needed):
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{ociamthesis}

% This adds a "DRAFT" footer to every normal page.  (The first page of each chapter is not a "normal" page.)
\fancyfoot[C]{\emph{DRAFT Printed on \today}}  

% This highlights (in blue) corrections marked with (for words) \mccorrect{blah} or (for whole
% paragraphs) \begin{mccorrection} . . . \end{mccorrection}.  This can be useful for sending a PDF of
% your corrected thesis to your examiners for review.  Turn it off, and the blue disappears.
\correctionstrue

% The humanities-type option: author-year in-text citation with an alphabetical works cited.
\usepackage[style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, backend=biber, maxcitenames=2, useprefix, doi=false, isbn=false]{biblatex}
\newcommand*{\bibtitle}{Works Cited}

%special characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% This makes the bibliography left-aligned (not 'justified') and slightly smaller font.
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\raggedright\small}

% Change this to the name of your .bib file (usually exported from a citation manager like Zotero or EndNote).
\addbibresource{references.bib}

%float package
\usepackage{float}

% package for lists
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hide=100, Hang=true, Progressive=3ex, Style*=-- ,
Style2*=$\bullet$ ,Style3*=$\circ$ ,Style4*=\tiny$\blacksquare$ )

%package for columns
\usepackage{multicol}

%varia
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands

%%%%% THE ACTUAL DOCUMENT STARTS HERE
\begin{document}
…
\include{text/ch1-intro}
…

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try looking in the `ociamthesis.cls` file instead.

Comment: If you can't see an explicit call to the package in your document, one of the pacakges or the documentclass must call that package internally. My guess is that the class `ociamthesis.cls` does that for you.

Comment: also never do this `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex use fontspec package

Comment: hey yes, it was in the ociamthesis.cls file, thank you very much.
Now it gives me an  "! Undefined control sequence.
\csq@main@language ->\xpg@main@language" error in correspondence of my "\begin{document}".. any idea?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue using `ociamthesis.cls` version 2.2. You do `\usepackage{polyglossia}`, but don't add a suitable `\setmainlanguage` declaration.